# Cassette.AssetReferenceException: Reference error in "~/Scripts/this.js", line 1. Cannot find "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"

Tags: javascript, asset-management, cassette

I cloned a git repo but have been unable to run the program due to the runtime error "`Cassette.AssetReferenceException`: Server Error in '/' Application. Reference error in "`~/Scripts/this.js`", line 1. Cannot find "`~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js`". "

At line 1 in this.js I have: /// `reference path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1`" / (the opening and closing brackets are included but if I add them here, it deletes my reference path)

I have Typscript for VS installed, the correct Cassette version, `jquery-1.7.1` IS in the scripts folder. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS.... I have no compiling errors in VS. I've recloned the repo a hundred times. I KNOW this repo is good because it works on another persons computer. So its definitely something with my setup and cassette. If I delete all the cassette references, my page loads (not properly, but I don't get anymore errors.)

I'm a little lost here. Has anyone ran into this before?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking I figured it out. 
2 things: 
Even after I uninstalled and reinstalled Cassette, for some reason, only the references for Cassette and Cassette.View were loading in my project. I had to manually brows for and add the reference for Cassette.Web.

Second thing is that in the _layout.cshtml file, I had to reference my jquery file like this:
@{ Bundles.Reference("Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"); }

INSTEAD OF

@{ Bundles.Reference("Scripts"); }
IDK why but it works now. someone else mentioned they had to something like that, too.